Not JSON serializable when using SQLAlchemy
Given the following code below
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, Mapped, DeclarativeBase, relationship
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer, ForeignKey, Column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class CModel(Base) :
    __tablename__ = 'c'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    cnp: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    cn: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    cs_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("cs.id"))

    cs = relationship("CSModel", foreign_keys=[cs_id])

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "cnp": self.cnp,
            "cn": self.cn,
            "cs": self.cs
        }

class CSModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cs'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    s: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String)
    so: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer)

I have followed the documentation found here. I have checked my database schema to make sure the models match correctly. I have looked over the documentation thrice and am still getting TypeError: Object of type CSModel is not JSON serializable. What am I missing?

Where in the linked documentation have you read that the model is JSON serializable?
